# Detect if tablet is in compatibility mode programmatically

Tags: android, tablet

Is there a way to detect that a tablet is currently running on compatibility mode?

I know that when it does, the whole Configuration settings are representing a much smaller screen than the tablet's screen, but how can I tell if this is a regular phone device with a small screen, or a tablet running compatibility zoom mode?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
    }
boolean istablet = isTablet(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: That won't work when the Tablet is in "zoom to fill screen" mode.